# Iterating over vectors of type Base and/or types derived from base

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I need to store objects of type Base, and of the derived types BaseDerivedA and BaseDerivedB. These objects need to be aligned in memory. I want to provide an iterator that iterates over all the objects. I'd like to avoid the memory overhead of storing a vector of Base pointers.

For this purpose I've built the following container

```
struct Container {
    std::vector<Base> bases;
    std::vector<BaseDerivedA> derivedAs;
    std::vector<BaseDerivedB> derivedBs;

    // Iterator over the three vectors
    all_iterator<Base> all_begin(){ return all_iterator(bases[0],this); }
    all_iterator<Base> end_begin(){ return all_iterator(nullptr,this); }

    // Where all_iterator is defined as
    template < class T >
    struct all_iterator
    : public boost::iterator_facade< all_iterator<T>,
                                     T, boost::forward_traversal_tag>
    {
        all_iterator() : it_(0) {}
        explicit all_iterator(T* p, Container* c) // THIS JUST FEELS WRONG
        : it_(p), c_(c) { }

    private:
        friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
        T* it_;
        Container* c_;
        void increment() {
            if (it_ == static_cast<T*>(&(c_->bases[c_->bases.size()-1]))) {
                it_ = static_cast<T*>(&(c_->derivedAs[0]));
            } else if (it_ == static_cast<T*>(&(c_->derivedAs[ds_->derivedAs.size()-1]))) {
                it_ = static_cast<T*>(&(c_->derivedBs[0]));
            } else if (it_ == static_cast<T*>(&(c_->derivedBs[ds_->derivedBs.size()-1]))) {
                it_ = nullptr; // THIS DOES ALSO FEEL WRONG
            } else {
                ++it_;
            }
        }
        bool equal(all_iterator const& other) const {
            return this->it_ == static_cast<T*>(other.it_);
        }
        T& dereference() const { return *it_; }
    };
```

I am using a nullptr as the one-past-the-end iterator as well as a lot of cast. I am also passing my iterator a pointer to the data structure.

Is it there a better way of iterating over three vectors containing the type Base or types derived from base?

Comment: You are hiding most of the important code, as for example what is `all_iterator` (how is it defined?) and how it uses it's arguments. The current implementation of your code (regardless of `all_iterator`) exhibits undefined behavior: you cannot access `derivedBs[derivedBs.size()]`, as that is an element beyond the end.

Comment: "I cannot assume that one past the end of derivedBs won't be the first element of derivedAs." - why is that? What is meant by that, considering that iterators to different containers are non-comparable?

Comment: Still, the code exhibits undefined behavior, which means that all bets are off. The approach is incorrect and you should try to find a *solution* rather than try to find how you can make undefined behavior work.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I have added the definition of the iterator :)

Comment: I don't understand the use case. Is BaseType the base class of DerivedA and DerivedB? Is there another class which is the common base of BaseType, DerivedA and DerivedB?

Comment: @MadScientist I have added the use case to the question. The point is I need the objects to be aligned in memory.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I've restated the question :)

Answer (score 2):

First we should note that your code has undefined behavior if `bases` is empty, or for any size of `derivedBs` if `end_begin` is called.

Is there a reason you can't that the more obvious and normal approach of having `BaseType*` or a smart variant in a single container, and using the abstract interface to access it, instead of that `dynamic_cast`/`static_cast` chain? Then the problem just goes away completely.

EDIT: If you need the memory of each type to be contiguous for some reason, and you don't do single `insert`s into the container frequently, just create a container of `BaseType` pointers that point to each object inside the derived object container(s). But I'd ask you to step back a moment and review *why* you need the objects to be contiguous (there could easily be a legitimate reason).

Comment: And something in the style of `boost::indirect_iterator` (from Boost.Iterators) would make it very easy to implement `all_begin`/`all_end` if there was such a container.

Comment: The only reason is that I need the elements of the vectors to be aligned in memory. Don't know if there is a better approach to that.

Comment: Thanks! The idea of the container of BaseType pointers is nice!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that BaseType is the common base of both DerivedA and DerivedB and you want to have a container that contains instances of DerivedA and DerivedB and gives you the capability to iterator over all DerivedA-instances, over all DerivedB-instances and over all instances of BaseType (i.e. the union of DerivedA's and DerivedB's). You could do that like this:

```
class BaseType
{
public:
  virtual void doit() const = 0;

  virtual ~BaseType() { }
};

class DerivedA : public BaseType
{
public:
  void doit() const { std::cout << "DerivedA::doit()" << std::endl; }

  void a() const { std::cout << "DerivedA::a()" << std::endl; }
};

class DerivedB : public BaseType
{
public:
  void doit() const { std::cout << "DerivedB::doit()" << std::endl; }

  void b() const { std::cout << "DerivedB::b()" << std::endl; }
};

class Container
{
public:
  void insert(DerivedA const & a)
  {
    m_as.push_back(a);
    m_base.push_back(&m_as.back());
  }

  void insert(DerivedB const & b)
  {
    m_bs.push_back(b);
    m_base.push_back(&m_bs.back());
  }

  std::vector<DerivedA>::iterator begin_a() { return m_as.begin(); }
  std::vector<DerivedA>::iterator end_a() { return m_as.end(); }
  std::vector<DerivedB>::iterator begin_b() { return m_bs.begin(); }
  std::vector<DerivedB>::iterator end_b() { return m_bs.end(); }
  std::vector<BaseType *>::iterator begin_all() { return m_base.begin(); }
  std::vector<BaseType *>::iterator end_all() { return m_base.end(); }

protected:
private:
  std::vector<DerivedA> m_as;
  std::vector<DerivedB> m_bs;
  std::vector<BaseType *> m_base;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice alternative. I need to check the memory overhead of having a vector of BaseType pointers :D

Answer (score 1):

For your iterator to be correct, you are going to have to know which vector you are currently traversing so that you can compare it properly.  You can do this by having an enumeration which tells you which one is current:

```
void all_iterator::increment()
{
  switch (current_member) {
    case BasesMember:
      ++bases_iter;
      if (bases_iter==bases.end()) {
        current_member = DerivedAsMember;
      }
      return;
    case DerivedAsMember:
      ++derived_as_iter;
      if (derived_as_iter==derivedAs.end()) {
        current_member = DerivedBsMember;
      }
      return;
    case DerivedBsMember:
      ++derived_bs_iter;
      if (derived_bs_iter==derivedBs.end()) {
        current_member = EndMember;
      }
      return;
    case EndMember:
      assert(current_member!=EndMember);
      break;
  }
} 

bool all_iterator::equal(all_iterator const &other) const
{
  if (current_member!=other.current_member) return false;
  switch (current_member) {
    case BasesMember:
      return bases_iter==other.bases_iter;
      break;
    case DerivedAsMember:
      return derived_as_iter==other.derived_as_iter;
      break;
    case DerivedBsMember:
      return derived_bs_iter==other.derived_bs_iter;
      break;
    case EndMember:
      return true
  }
}

Base& all_iterator::dereference() const
{
  switch (current_member) {
    case BasesMember:     return *bases_iter;
    case DerivedAsMember: return *derived_as_iter;
    case DerivedBsMember: return *derived_bs_iter;
    case EndMember:
      assert(current_member!=EndMember);
      break;
  }
  return *bases_iter;
}
```

Comment: If the vectors are of type Base or of a type derived from base, can't I just cast to base in the comparisons?

Comment: No, you are actually going to need three separate iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it matter what is located at `derivedAs.end()`? You will never access/modify it through `derivedAs`. So you don't need that assumption at all.

Typical code would be

```
for(auto it = derivedAs.begin(); it != derivedAs.end(); ++it) {
    *it = // do whatever, will never do *derivedAs.end()
}
```

Comment: What is located at derivedBs.end() matters. If derivedBs.end() == derivedAs.begin() loops break.

Comment: @gnzlbg it's illegal to compare iterators obtained from different containers.

Comment: @ecatmur For this reason I have supplied my own iterator instead.